# Visual Studio 2010 Loading Cursor is Flashing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cursor

The loading cursor that looks like a sand timer. Every time I open VS2010 and open or create any new project, the loading cursor flashes every ~2secs on and off even when VS2010 is minimized.

Cursor does not flash while viewing the options window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention OS, but an easy way to see what is going on in Windows 7 and vista is to run resource monitor (start-> type "Resmon"). Check the disk tab especially to see vs2010 file activity.

An alternative application is (freeware) process explorer from Microsoft (formerly Sysinternals)

Comment: I'm running Windows XP.

Comment: Process explorer has a bottom pane which shows file handles (files open by an application) which might give you some insight on what it is doing. There are also free progs from MS called regmon and filemon to show in-depth file and registry activity by applications. Too much info, but you can filter output by application.

Comment: In Process Explorer from Sysinternals, the Disk and Network tab shows Disk I/O, Reads: 6, Read Byes: 100.0KB. The rest are 0's.

Comment: Interesting, I went to the threads tab and suspending vcpkg.dll!DllGetClassObject+0x86e6. I'm not sure if this is vital to the program but it suspending the thread fixes the flashing mouse issue.

Comment: Looks like IntelliSense (auto-complete, code formatting).
Check ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx ) for some info about configuration. Lots of Google noise, but it looks a little buggy.

Comment: Yeah, it was intellisense. I resumed the thread, went to Tools > Options then Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > IntelliSense. Disabled Error Reporting and the description states "Disables reporting of IntelliSense errors through squiggles and the Error List Window. Also disables the background parsing associated with error reporting." Thanks for the help, Horatio.

Comment: @Gio Borje: FYI it is not enough to accept - the bounty has to be manually awarded.